# Django Admin escaping text

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I recently upgraded Django from 1.3 to 1.8.18 and been having issues with links custom made to pre-fill forms in Django admin. For example, I have the following link:

```
/admin/miscellaneous/whatsnew/add/?title=...%20competition%20results%20uploaded&pub_date=21-04-2017&body=&link=
```

When executed the pre-filled data in the form looks like:
[image]

Where it should look like this:

[image]

When testing directly from the URL bar in Safari it changes to this after pressing enter:

```
https://flyball.org.au/admin/miscellaneous/whatsnew/add/?title=...%2520competition%2520results%2520uploaded&pub_date=21-04-2017&body=&link=
```

**models.py**

```
class WhatsNew(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text='Title, MAX 100 characters.')
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    message_expiry = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(years=1))
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name_plural = "Whats New?"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**admin.py**

```
import models
from django.contrib import admin

class WhatsNewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','pub_date','message_expiry','link','body')

admin.site.register(models.WhatsNew, WhatsNewAdmin)
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Could you also show the code responsible for filling this form i.e. reading `title` from the query params and feeding it to the form?

Comment: @AKS I am not doing any sort of special code here its part of Django, not sure where to find it

Comment: It does work for me. I tried with `%20` and it results into space in the admin form.

Comment: @AKS it used to work for me too, prior to upgrading to Django 1.8

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working. I have `django 1.8.17` and it is working there.

Comment: I see what it happening in the safari. It is trying to encode the URL and as a result is encoding the already encoded value of `title` query param. Do you have any other browser where you can test it i.e. chrome? If not you can try in safari with `space` in place of `%20`.

Comment: Tested the URL in Chrome and it behaves correctly, but is different in Safari. Just did the URL without `%20` in Safari and the outcome was the same

Comment: This is working for me in Django 1.10. Just for fun, try using `+` instead of `%20`, since that's what the admin does by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `%20` for space and it works.

Your link should be something like:

```
/admin/miscellaneous/whatsnew/add/?title=...+competition+results+uploaded&pub_date=21-04-2017&body=&link=
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm not sure how to do it on the ModelAdmin, but you can create custom setters on your model to handle this situation. Here's how I would go about escaping the URL encoded strings:

```
import urllib


class WhatsNew(models.Model):
    # Field with custom setter
    _title = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                             help_text='Title, MAX 100 characters.',
                             db_column='title')

    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    message_expiry = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(years=1))
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    # Custom getter and setter
    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @title.setter
    def title(self, value):
        self._title = urllib.unquote(value)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name_plural = "Whats New?"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self._title
```

Comment: This is interesting, haven't seen it done before. I just used the `+` symbols and it seems to have resolved it. Thanks

Comment: I've just seen issues, specifically in chrome, where it will prevent you from putting symbols in the URL and encode it automatically for you. I thought that might be what's happening, but I guess not! Glad everything worked out!